# Can I use math on argument variables in a for loop?

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm writing my first bash script and I'm trying to parse arguments. I have a

```
for arg in "$@"
```

loop set up, but I want some arguments to be read together, for instance if the user passes -a info it would find out what $number -a is and also read $number + 1. Is this something I can do?

I could make the loop keep $count ++ each iteration to tell what arg I'm on, and since my script is set to bomb out if it finds something invalid, I set an if statement to continue if a $skip var is above 0, I just need to figure out how to read $arg +1.

I haven't tried much. I'm still new (my first script) at this and I don't know too many commands. Google got me this far, but I hit a wall.

Comment: Maybe it's better to take a step back and instead ask [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `for arg in "$@"` syntax, you can write:

```sh
for (( i = 1 ; i <= ${#} ; ++i )) ; do
  arg="${@:i:1}"           # current argument
  next_arg="${@:i+1:1}"    # next argument
  ...
done
```

The `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 ))` syntax is described in [the *Bash Reference Manual*, § 3.2.4.1 Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs); the `${@:expr:expr}` syntax is described in [§ 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). Both rely on shell arithmetic, which is described in [§ 6.5 Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic).